# How to prevent a windows form from disappearing on a modal appear?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, powerpoint

As part of a powerpoint add-in, I show the user a windows form with information about a color (like RGB values), which he can copy and paste within the modal for color (shape -> right click -> fill color -> more fill colors).

The problem is that as soon as the form loses focus, it minimizes, and I am unable to access it when the color modal is open.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Maybe make it a dialog and remove the minimize button?

Comment: I can't open the color dialog for a shape if i make my form the dialog (as I can't click on anything in powerpoint).

Comment: This is not unusual.  You are doing it wrong.  But nobody can see you doing it wrong, this is not youtube.